# OpenXML determine position of axis in chart

Tags: charts, openxml, scatter-plot

I am using category charts for a project and would like to switch to scatter charts. The issue I am facing is how to replicate the category labels as shown in the following picture:
[image: Category chart]

My only idea is to hide the x axis for the scatter chart and add textbox shapes under the chart at the correct positions. The hard part is calculating the positions within the chart for the textboxes.

The x axis is automatically sized and positioned by each application (Excel, LibreCalc etc) differently depending on various factors (title size, axis titles, legend position/overlaying etc).

The textboxes are defined in the `userShapes` part of DrawingML and their positioning is defined by Excel by the relative coordinates of the shape to their parent chart via a `relSizeAnchor`:

```
<cdr:relSizeAnchor xmlns:cdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chartDrawing">
    <cdr:from>
        <cdr:x>0.2</cdr:x>
        <cdr:y>0.75</cdr:y>
    </cdr:from>
    <cdr:to>
        <cdr:x>0.85</cdr:x>
        <cdr:y>0.4</cdr:y>
    </cdr:to>
</cdr:relSizeAnchor>
```

Is there any way I could calculate the axis position within the chart in any form, so that I can calculate the textbox relative positions? Using a `manualLayout` for the plot area *could* work but I would really prefer a different solution.